# Checking whether all files were extracted correctly

Tags: synology, 7z

I have a bunch of large zip files on a Synology. The Synology built-in extractor is a bit fiddly, and I'd like to check whether the files were extracted correctly using the commandline. Installed is `7z`, and the "standard" Linux tools. What are some methods I can make sure the files were all extracted correctly?

I've tried asking GPT for some answers, but it only told me that I use `-t` to test whether the files *inside* the zip aren't corrupted. The 7z manual also didn't look like it supported this out of the box, or I missed it, which is totally possible. Obviously, I searched the internet and StackOverflow as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think you, or GPT(*), are confusing 7z commands with 7z options. Or perhaps confusing `7z` with Info-ZIP's `unzip` program.

The `7z` man page documents a `t` **command** to "Test integrity of archive".

The `-t` **option** is unrelated and allows the user to set the type of archive.

(*) don't rely on answers from so-called "AI" - it's not actual AI, it's not even close to anything resembling AI.  Everything currently claimed to be Artifical Intelligence is just a [stochastic parrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_parrot) - jumped up, over-hyped auto-incorrect. Markov chain generators not all that much more sophisticated than those written in the 1990s, just a whole lot more [garbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) fed into them.

---

BTW, Info-ZIP's `unzip` program has a `-t` option to test archives.  From `man unzip`:

> `-t`     test  archive  files.
>
> This option extracts each specified file in memory and compares the CRC (cyclic redundancy check, an enhanced checksum) of the expanded file with the original file’s stored CRC value.

`unzip` is an entirely separate program, unrelated to `7z`. different source code, different authors, different everything.  The only connection is that both 7z and unzip can work with zip files.

Comment: Although this didn't exactly answer OPs question, +1 for your accurate take on the marketing label "AI". It is nice to see I am not alone out there. ;-)